# Can you comment on specific highlights of R code?

Tags: ide, rstudio

Is there a feature in Rstudio (or other IDEs compatible with R) where you can highlight and comment pieces of code similar to a highlighted comment in MS word (e.g. screenshot below)?

[image]

Comment: No, that feature isn't possible. The most common step is to the use `#` character to comment out lines and place comments there.

Comment: Yes but with lengthy pieces of code, the `#` is not practical to highlight a specific section of the code

Comment: You can file a feature request at https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio

Comment: What problem do you want to solve, @CyG? Do you want to create a tutorial? If you want an extended narration about the code, would `R Markdown` or `Quarto` be an option for you?

Comment: The problem is that writing "`#` comment" in you script can clutter the script and doesn't necessarily point to a specifc part of the code you wish to refer to. 
In constrast, in MS word, you can select a specific part of your document, right click, "add comment". Now the comment is stored on a side tab and when your mouse hovers over the highlited section, the comment appears. Hope that's clearer. FYI I filed a feature request on github. https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/11911